# How to write a FreeMarker template function with no input parameters

Tags: java, freemarker

Is it possible to write a **FTL function** with no input parameters?

Like in Java where you can write `void test() {}`, which takes no arguments and returns nothing.

I have read the [documentation](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_function.html). But could not find much information on this particular topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not taking any arguments is just like `<#function f>...</#function>`.

Not returning a value is also possible by simply not calling `<#return someValue>`, and reaching `</#function>`. However, a function that returns nothing is generally a bad idea. Then it's more likely that what you want is a macro (see the `macro` directive). In FTL functions are about returning a value, while macros are about side-effects (like printing to the output, or launching a rocket).

Comment: ok thanks.. I have defined function f as you told. and called using  ${f()}. but it throws following error  "FreeMarker template error:
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> f()". can you help me on the same.

Comment: Right. In almost all situation you want to use the return value FreeMarker will be agitated, as there's none. So, if you don't need a return value, why use a function instead of a macro?

Comment: Regarding "${f()}. but it throws following error": Technically this happens because you try to print a null value, which you can't, if you do `${f()!'nope'}`, it will print "nope".